# Passing events to parent

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, event-handling

I'd like to create an app where some events are supposed to be handled as if they were delivered to parent containers. For example I've got a `JPanel` which contains `JLabel`. The top `JPanel` implements mousepress and dragging right now. What do I need to do, in order to make the events look like they arrived to `JPanel` instead of the label itself. (changing source object is important)

Is there some better solution than actually implementing the events and replicating them in the parent? (this would get tedious after some objects with >5 children).

Comment: Why do you need to do this (example)?

Comment: I've got objects with many labels, that should be draggable wherever they're actually clicked the first time. Right now they're draggable only when I click on the background of the element, not any label inside.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At your event listener, you can dispatch the event to the parent component.

Being `myEvent` the event handling function argument:

```
Component source=(Component)myEvent.getSource();
source.getParent().dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

But this solution implies creating a new EventListener for each element to add.

So, you could create a single event handler and reuse it, adding it to all the chosen children, like this:

```
final Container parent=this; //we are a the parent container creation code
MouseListener myCommonListener=new MouseListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        parent.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        parent.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        parent.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        parent.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        parent.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
};

JLabel label=new JLabel("This is the first Label");
label.addMouseListener(myCommonListener);

JLabel label2=new JLabel("This is the second Label");
label2.addMouseListener(myCommonListener);
//... and so on
```

Comment: This created a stack overflow in awt thread (as the parent was passing the event back to the child control). Any ideas on how to get around this problem? I can't edit the parent class, yet I need it to get the event but prevent acting on the event that the parent will pass back to my control.

Comment: Resource-wise this is a bad idea. You're adding a lot of overhead for nothing. It's much more efficient to remove the mouse listeners on the child elements. You can see my answer for how to do that recursively.

Answer (score 6):

You should convert event before dispatching it to the parent. Conversion includes coordinates translation to parent-relative.

```
public class RedispatchingMouseAdapter implements MouseListener, MouseWheelListener, MouseMotionListener{

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        redispatchToParent(e);
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        redispatchToParent(e);
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        redispatchToParent(e);
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        redispatchToParent(e);
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        redispatchToParent(e);
    }

    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e){
        redispatchToParent(e);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        redispatchToParent(e);
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        redispatchToParent(e);
    }

    private void redispatchToParent(MouseEvent e){
        Component source = (Component) e.getSource();
        MouseEvent parentEvent = SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(source, e, source.getParent());
        source.getParent().dispatchEvent(parentEvent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is actually a comment to Tomas Narros' answer.

Comment: @SeniorJD This is a perfectly valid answer. It simply builds on the other answer and can stand on its own. It would be better if Wojtek would describe a little more why this adjustment is needed.

Comment: Resource-wise this is a bad idea. You're adding a lot of overhead for nothing. It's much more efficient to remove the mouse listeners on the child elements. You can see my answer for how to do that recursively.

Answer (score 3):

Mouse events are automatically targeted to the deepest component that **has mouse listeners**.

Because of this, to achieve your goal, you can simply remove all mouse listeners on the JLabel and it will never get picked as the target for mouse events.

The following code will disable mouse listeners on the given components and their children recursively:

```
public static void disableMouseForComponent(Component... components) {
    for (Component c : components) {
        if (c instanceof Container) {
            disableMouseForComponent(((Container) c).getComponents());
        }
        for (MouseListener l : c.getMouseListeners()) {
            c.removeMouseListener(l);
        }
        for (MouseMotionListener l : c.getMouseMotionListeners()) {
            c.removeMouseMotionListener(l);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Person who -1'ed: do you care to explain why?
Doing it this way is much better resource wise than adding a listener that dispatches to the parent.

Comment: I tried this with KeyListeners, instead - it didn't propagate up to the parent; just got absorbed.  (I had to disable `focusable` and possibly `requestFocusEnable`.)  If the same holds true for mouse listeners, that may be why they downvoted you.  Did you test your solution to make sure it works?

Comment: @Erhannis KeyListeners are pretty different. This solution has been in prod for years at my company, works great.

Comment: Subclassing it and calling your method as well as `disableEvents(AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK);` did it for me.