# how can events work on top of listening children components?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm doing the challenge (and also need to) of making my own window so that I can customize it even more than what swing is capable of.

So far everything has been going fine, I can do everything that a normal windows window can do, except resizing. I wanted to start by detecting when the mouse is getting near the edge using a MouseMotionListener and capturing the MouseMoved event. It works as a planned except. Here's a code sample:

```
public class foo extends MouseAdapter
{
  private JFrame frame
  private Point p;

  public foo(JFrame bar)
  {
    frame = bar;
  }

  @Override
  public void MouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
  {
    apoint = e.getPoint();
    System.out.println(apoint.toString());
  }
}
```

.... Somewhere else

```
public class zoof extends JFrame
{
  public zoof()
  {
   setSize(500,500);
   setUndecorated(true);
   JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
   panel.setSize(500, 100);
   JPanel cpanel = new JPanel();
   panel.addMouseListener(new x(this));
   panel.addMouseMotionListener(new x(this));
   Xbutton c = new Xbutton();
   Ebutton e = new Ebutton();
   HButton m = new Hbutton();
   addMouseMotionListener(new foo(this));
   panel.add(sh);
   panel.add(ex);
   panel.add(close);
   add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
   add(cpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }
}
```

The outputs works very nicely except when the mouse goes on top of panel (the panel with the buttons). I got two hypothesizes on why this might not work

1. the thread  is not allowing the frame listener to react because the panel already is listening and can't focus on the jframe listener.
2. the panel listener overrides the jframe listener

whichever or whatever case it is, it's definitely something I'd like you guys input on. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your second code block intended to be a constructor?

Comment: Ah crud let me edit that

Comment: and for the record only 1 thread is maintaining it using an event queue

Comment: Class names should start with an upper case charcter.

Comment: Please excuse the example code I made in 5 minutes.

Comment: (1-) the code you post should be proper code. We are not here to read code created in a hurry. The code you post should be tested which means you should write it properly and test it and debug it. And if takes no more time to use proper names than it does to use incorrect names.

Comment: I'd accept this if you event tried to answer my question. I get it.  However, naming convention won't break code in anyway and its source code from my own program so yes its been tested. I simply changed the class and method names so people can follow it easier.

Comment: @Deluparam and I would have provided an answer if a proper question with proper code was posted. If you make an effort to ask a good question you will get a good answer. You made no effort and appear unwilling to even try to make a better question.

Comment: What is a good question?

Comment: Btw your code won't compile, and yes because of code convention. MouseMoved should be mouseMoved, otherwise it won't override.

Comment: right. thanks. I'll make sure that my code is perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your solution is not the right approach IMHO. I wouldn't care for motion events, just for mouse dragging events if the start point (the mouse pressed) is at border area.

Now, for your question what makes your listener not react to these events; non of your hypotheses are correct, the event just won't be sent to a parent if a listening child is found. Try removing your panel's listener and the frame should receive the events. Take a look in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818246/passing-events-to-parent) for info how to forward events.

Comment: Oh I had no Idea. This is the time I do graphic programming in java (in general tbh). Also was would be your solution to detect a a mouse near an undecorated jframe border?

Comment: I'm also planning to use mdevents but the mouse move event is to change the cursor when it gets close to the border, I know, a waste of processing power for something simple isn't the best but until I find a better itll work like that.

Comment: Simply by doing some calculations on the point of event. Check if x-y is less than 5 or more than frame's width - 5 or height - 5 respectively

Comment: yeah, I knew this the current code is just to test if the event works as I expected. thanks :)

Comment: @Delupara once again a little edit, about the term "overrides".